# Errors in javascript and queries in Xquery

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xquery

I want to query XQuery every time I click on a checkbox. The result will be displayed in a part of the page that will be updated. The problem is that I make them from the products.xqy file, where also the html code for the page. I get errors with Javascript, which disappear when I use the CDATE, but also do not take the Javascript code. When i use the code in html and without the Xquery code, has no errors.
The ideal then would be to have an .xqy file for each query that I do. Any idea how to do this?
I leave the code:

productos.xqy

```
    <html lang="es-AR">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles/bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">Tienda de Electrodomesticos</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        Filtros 
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Precio"></input>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Precio</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck2"></input>
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <td id ="contenido"></td>
                <div class="col-10" id="1">
                    <div class="row">
                        {  
                        for $x in doc("resources/productos.xml")/productos/producto  
                        order by $x/nombre  
                        return
                                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">{data($x/nombre)}</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">Categoría: {data($x/@category)}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                        <li class="list-group-item">{data($x/tipo)}</li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">{data($x/specs)}</li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item">{data($x/precio)}</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                        }
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                {
                                for $x in doc("resources/productos.xml")/productos/producto
                                where $x/precio>20000 and $x/precio<100000  
                                return
                                <p>
                                {data($x/nombre)}
                                {data($x/precio)}   
                                </p>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            <![CDATA[
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#1').change(function () {
                        if (this.checked) {
                            // Se debe cargar una página hosteada en un servidor no en un archivo y se puede especificar una clase o id.
                            $("#contenido").load("https://montesariel.com/es/contactos .heading");
                        }
                        if (!this.checked) {
                            // Elimina el contenido si se desmarca la selección.
                            $("#contenido").html("");
                        }
                    });
                });
            ]]>
        </script>
    </body>  
</html>
```

AppXQuery class:

```
package xquery;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.xquery.XQConnection;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQDataSource;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQException;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQPreparedExpression;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQResultSequence;

import com.saxonica.xqj.SaxonXQDataSource;

public class AppXQuery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        execute();
    }

    private static void execute() {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("resources/productos.xqy"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        XQDataSource ds = new SaxonXQDataSource();
        XQConnection conn;
        XQPreparedExpression exp;
        XQResultSequence result = null;
        try {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            exp = conn.prepareExpression(inputStream);
            result = exp.executeQuery();
        } catch (XQException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("index.html");
            while (result.next()) {
//              System.out.println(result.getItemAsString(null));
                myWriter.write(result.getItemAsString(null));
            }
            myWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Archivo generado");
        } catch (XQException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

productos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<productos>
   
   <producto category="TECNOLOGIA">
      <nombre lang="es">Smart TV Samsung 50 " 4K Ultra HD UN50TU7000GCZB</nombre>
      <tipo>Televisor</tipo>
      <specs>
        <pulgadas>50</pulgadas>
        <resolucionv>4K Ultra HD</resolucionv>
        <ancho>112</ancho>
        <alto>65</alto>
        <profundidad>5.91</profundidad>
      </specs>
      <precio>56999.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="TECNOLOGIA">
      <nombre lang="es">Smart TV Philips 32 " HD 32PHG5813/77</nombre>
      <tipo>Televisor</tipo>
      <specs>
        <pulgadas>32</pulgadas>
        <resolucionv>HD</resolucionv>
        <ancho>73.53</ancho>
        <alto>43.53</alto>
        <profundidad>7.73</profundidad>
      </specs>
      <precio>25499.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="TECNOLOGIA">
      <nombre lang="es">Smart TV Samsung 75 " 4K Ultra HD UN75RU7100GCZB</nombre>
      <tipo>Televisor</tipo>
      <specs>
        <pulgadas>75</pulgadas>
        <resolucionv>4K Ultra HD</resolucionv>
        <ancho>168.89</ancho>
        <alto>97.12</alto>
        <profundidad>6.6</profundidad>
      </specs>
      <precio>249499.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="TECNOLOGIA">
      <nombre lang="es">QLED Samsung 65 " Ultra HD QN65Q70TAGCZB</nombre>
      <tipo>Televisor</tipo>
      <specs>
        <pulgadas>65</pulgadas>
        <resolucionv>Ultra HD</resolucionv>
        <ancho>144.96</ancho>
        <alto>82.93</alto>
        <profundidad>5.76</profundidad>
      </specs>
      <precio>134999.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="TECNOLOGIA">
      <nombre lang="es">Notebook HP 15-cw1027la AMD Ryzen 7</nombre>
      <tipo>Notebook</tipo>
      <specs>
        <pantalla>15.6"</pantalla>
        <resolucionp>1920 x 1080</resolucionp>
        <salidavga>No</salidavga>
        <tactil>No</tactil>
        <os>Windows 10 Home</os>
      </specs>
      <precio>107999.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="TECNOLOGIA">
      <nombre lang="es">Notebook HP DY1971cl Premium 15.6 " Intel Core i7 8 GB DDR4</nombre>
      <tipo>Notebook</tipo>
      <specs>
        <pantalla>15.6"</pantalla>
        <resolucionp>1920 x 1080</resolucionp>
        <salidavga>No</salidavga>
        <tactil>Si</tactil>
        <os>Linux Ubuntu</os>
      </specs>
      <precio>154999.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="ELECTRODOMESTICOS">
      <nombre lang="es">Cocina Longvie 56 cm. 19501B Multigas Blanca</nombre>
      <tipo>Cocina</tipo>
      <specs>
        <color>Blanco</color>
        <ancho>56</ancho>
        <alto>85</alto>
        <profundidad>59</profundidad>
      </specs>
      <precio>75799.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="ELECTRODOMESTICOS">
      <nombre lang="es">Cocina ESCORIAL 56 cm Master Gas Natural Negra</nombre>
      <tipo>Cocina</tipo>
      <specs>
        <color>Negro</color>
        <ancho>56</ancho>
        <alto>93</alto>
        <profundidad>60</profundidad>
      </specs>
      <precio>20999.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="ELECTRODOMESTICOS">
      <nombre lang="es">Secarropas Kohinoor A-665/2</nombre>
      <tipo>Secarropa</tipo>
      <specs>
        <capacidad>6.5</capacidad>
        <ancho>40</ancho>
        <alto>69.5</alto>
        <profundidad>50</profundidad>
      </specs>
      <precio>54499.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="ELECTRODOMESTICOS">
      <nombre lang="es">Lavarropas Automático Drean 10 KG Next 10.12 P ECO</nombre>
      <tipo>Lavarropa</tipo>
      <specs>
        <tipocarga>Frontal</tipocarga>
        <capacidad>10</capacidad>
        <ancho>65</ancho>
        <alto>85</alto>
        <profundidad>56</profundidad>
      </specs>
      <precio>14990.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="CASA Y JARDIN">
      <nombre lang="es">Farol LED Artelum Nano 7 W. 30 x 11 Cm. Gris</nombre>
      <tipo>Lámpara</tipo>
      <specs>
        <tipo>LED</tipo>
        <resolucionv>Ultra HD</resolucionv>
        <ancho>11</ancho>
        <alto>30</alto>
        <profundidad>30</profundidad>
      </specs>
      <precio>5891.00</precio>
   </producto>
   
   <producto category="CASA Y JARDIN">
      <nombre lang="es">Termotanque a Gas Rheem 80 L TGNC080RH</nombre>
      <tipo>Termotanque</tipo>
      <specs>
        <capacidad>80</capacidad>
        <peso>32</peso>
        <alto>111.2</alto>
        <diametro>51</diametro>
      </specs>
      <precio>38999.00</precio>
   </producto>

</productos>
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you have written Java code to execute XQuery and write the result to `index.html`? Do you then load the HTML document into a browser? Is that when the Javascript execution fails? It might be worth looking at that XQuery generated HTML, although reduced to a minimum. I am not really familiar with the used `javax.xml.xquery` API but perhaps to ensure proper HTML serialization there better/more appropriate ways to use it.

Comment: Without the Javascript this code works fine. The issue aside from the Javascript is what I want to do next. I want to make queries and each one of them is displayed in an HTML page.